# Webkit browsers clipping italic font on left side

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts

I'm running into an issue on my personal splash page with a handwritten Google webfont, Meddon. What's happening is that, seemingly at random, Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, iOS Safari) are clipping the left side of the font.

You can see the issue on [my personal page](http://www.joshuahiggins.com). The left side of the JH will appear/disappear at random, when refreshing or resizing the page.

Anyone know of a solution for this? Even better, does anyone know what's causing this behavior?

Comment: I think it's maybe to do with the negative left margin on .circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `jh` container width is not sufficient, take a look here

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BKz4/)

Update `.jh` class like this - [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7BKz4/1/)

```
.circle .jh {
    margin-top: 50px; /* You can adjust this */
    font-family: "Meddon";
    font-size: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ff8e00;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Since it was happening sporadically, I thought it was more of a bug rather than just poor wrapping.

Comment: @one800higgins I generally use `outline` or `border` when am designing ;) and you welcome